# Typescript make property of object type required if the value type exist as property of generic object

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

How to make property of object type required or optional or even hidden when the type of the value does not exist in Typescript generics as object?

```
type ActionBaseType {
    payload?: any
    extra?: any
}

type Action<ActionType extends ActionBaseType = ActionBaseType> = {
    extra?: ActionType['extra']
    payload?: ActionType['payload']
} 

// here I should not be able to pass payload or it should be optional, 
// since I did not give a type to payload
const action: Action<{extra: number}> = {extra: 1}   

// here the value should REQUIRE me to pass payload
const action: Action<{extra: number, payload: {id: number}}> = {extra: 1, payload: {id: 2}}
```

What I tried and did not work:

```
 type Action<ActionType extends ActionBaseType = ActionBaseType> = {
     extra?: ActionType['extra']
     payload?: ActionType['payload'] extends never ? undefined : ActionType['payload']
 } 
 // and
 type Action<ActionType extends ActionBaseType = ActionBaseType> = {
     extra?: ActionType['extra']
 } & (ActionType['payload'] extends never ? {} : {payload: ActionType['payload']})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking if the payload extends any seems to do the trick here

```
type ActionBaseType = {
    payload?: any
    extra?: any
}

type Action<ActionType extends ActionBaseType = ActionBaseType> = ActionType extends {
    payload: any
}
    ? {
          extra?: ActionType['extra']
          payload: ActionType['payload']
      }
    : {
          extra?: ActionType['extra']
          payload?: ActionType['payload']
      }
```